# Inject field in a grails domain class dynamically

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a problem in a grails application. My application use a plugin to generate some domain models, I need to add a field to one of those domain models and I don't have the source code. Is there a way to do it dynamically? For example using the GORM API the metaclass or something like that?

Comment: Can you just add the domain objects to you project?  Why do you need methods in those domain objects?

Comment: No I can't add the domain object...I don't have the source code. I need this field that is the status of that object, so I need to put it there

Comment: what plugin is it? If it is a plugin you DO have the source in your ~/.grails directory btw

Comment: The plugin isn't made by me...I just have the JAR and I can't have the source code...because it's made by a company...

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just extend the class from the plugin and add your field.  That is a common thing to do with plugins like Spring Security Core.

```
    class MyUser extends SecUser {
        String phoneNumber
        ...
    }
```

Comment: no, I can't because I have this object that are used from "framework" of the application, and I don't have the source code of it. If I can't extend it, because I don't create the object in the application, so I can't use it. I need to inject this field in the object

Comment: If it's a Grails plugin you actually do have the source code, but you don't need the source code to extend a class.

Comment: I can't have the source because the plugin is made by another company and I can't extend the class because a piece of application use that class...so also if I extend that class the application will continue to use the old one, and when an entity is saved I don't know how to transfor it in another class